# Image URL in React

Tags: reactjs, url

I am using the same image URL structure for every component in my application, however, one of them shows my image URL wrong. It basically adds 'menu' in front of the image URL.

Correct URL: /images/pizza.png

Rendered URL: /menu/images/pizza.png

I have a menu and detail component. When I click on a dish on the menu, I show the details component which is related to the dish.

Before rendering my image, I printed out the URL of the image, it shows the correct URL(without 'menu' string), however, after renders it, 'menu' is added in front of the image URL and the image is not shown.

Menu Component: (It shows image URL correctly)

```
function RenderMenuItem({ dish }) {
return(
    <Card>
        <Link to={`/restaurant/menu/${dish.id}`}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
        </Link>
    </Card>

);
}
```

Detail Component: (It shows image URL wrong)

```
function RenderDish({ dish }) {
if (dish) {
    return (
        <FadeTransform in
        transformProps={{
            exitTransform: 'scale(0.5) translateY(-50%)'
        }}>
        <Card>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
        </FadeTransform>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
}
```

Related routes:

```
 <Route exact path="/restaurant/menu" component={() => <Menu dishes= 
 {this.props.dishes} /> } />

 <Route path="/restaurant/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />
```

Comment: Add some `console.log()` and figure out why it's not being passed correctly. My guess is you forgot a `/` at the start to mark the path as absolute.

Comment: Have you tried `./imgPath` instead of `/imgPath`?

Comment: I didn't forget a `/`.  I really don't know where the problem is.

Comment: @L.Norman The problem should be specific. I render a lot of images in the same way, but the problem happens in only the Detail Component and somehow it could be related Menu component. I added related routes to my post.

Comment: Pretty sure this is caused by the image url itself. It is taken as relative from current path and not from the root. That means it is missing `/` at the start.